# Bypassing google api in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Dear stackoverflower,

I'm currently using wordpress with alpine theme to create a new company website, but the Google api is slowing down the site, is there a way I can't disable all servers from Google?

BTW, I got google font disabled by "Disable Google Fonts", but when I using other theme, this might not work. I'm from China and yes, google is grounded here.

Regards,
Tonny

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove #_MAP from your formats and the Google libraries won't be loaded.